# How do I change the theme in an AnyChart React tag cloud?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, word-cloud, anychart, tag-cloud

I am creating a tag cloud word cloud using the React library from AnyChart. How do I change the color theme of it? The [answer found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43491444/anychart-react-set-a-theme) doesn't seem to work:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import AnyChart from "anychart-react";
import anychart from "anychart";
anychart.theme("coffee");

var data = [
  { x: "learning", value: 80 },
  { x: "includes", value: 56 },
  { x: "lists", value: 44 },
  { x: "meaning", value: 40 },
  { x: "useful", value: 36 },
  { x: "different", value: 32 },
  { x: "grammar", value: 28 },
  { x: "teaching", value: 24 },
  { x: "example", value: 20 },
  { x: "thing", value: 12 }
];

// create a chart and set the data
var chart = anychart.tagCloud(data);
//chart.theme = anychart.palettes.coffee;

ReactDOM.render(
  <AnyChart width={800} height={600} instance={chart} title="Column chart" />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Full demo [is here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-forked-cpynl?file=/index.js:0-734)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is available if you are using the `instance` attribute. THe idea is to create the chart with the usual library API, and then apply this instance to the component. In this case, all library features are available via API.
So, you can use this call

```
chart.theme = anychart.palettes.coffee;
```

in the instance. For details, check [the live sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-t6pnc).

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I have that commented out in my question also because it didn't work. It works in the plain Javascript library but not the React library

Comment: Make sure that you included the JS of the coffee theme.

Comment: I thought I did in my demo I posted but maybe I did it wrong. Here is a modified version of your sample but it doesn't seem to work either: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-forked-4vl50?file=/index.html

Comment: Theme JS files are simple self-invoked functions. They are not available as modules via NPM. Importing them as JS side-effect JS scripts will not work in React. So, you need to convert the desired theme to a module. For details, check the modified sample - https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-forked-dd9d3?file=/coffee.js